# add control in first row of each column in grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I wan to add a simple link button in `gridview's` first row in all columns . I have written code on `rowdatabound` event

my code is as follow

```
protected void grdCompareProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {


            PlaceHolder col1 = e.Row.FindControl("col1") as PlaceHolder;
            PlaceHolder col2 = e.Row.FindControl("col2") as PlaceHolder;
            PlaceHolder col3 = e.Row.FindControl("col3") as PlaceHolder;
            PlaceHolder col4 = e.Row.FindControl("col4") as PlaceHolder;

            LinkButton lnkProductName = new LinkButton();
            lnkProductName.Text = "Product Name";




            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                if (col1 != null)
                {

                    col1.Controls.Add(lnkProductName);
                    col2.Controls.Add(lnkProductName);
                    col3.Controls.Add(lnkProductName);
                    col4.Controls.Add(lnkProductName);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

but its showing  link button only in last column . HTML for  grid view as follow ..

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCompareProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            ShowHeader="false" CssClass="compare-info" Width="100%" CellPadding="6" CellSpacing="0"
            OnRowCommand="grdCompareProducts_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdCompareProducts_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblHeader" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("header") %>' CssClass="header_strong"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="col1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="col2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="col3" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="col4" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the problem, think you can just try creating a new instance for each column.
 i.e change if condition as

```
 LinkButton lnkProductName;
    if (col1 != null)
                {
            lnkProductName= new LinkButton();
            lnkProductName.Text = "Product Name";
                    col1.Controls.Add(lnkProductName);
            lnkProductName= new LinkButton();
            lnkProductName.Text = "Product Name2";
                    col2.Controls.Add(lnkProductName);
                }
```

similarly for other columns

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            if (col1 != null)
            {
                LinkButton lnkProductNameCol1 = new LinkButton();
                lnkProductNameCol1.Text = "Product Name";                   
                col1.Controls.Add(lnkProductNameCol1);

                LinkButton lnkProductNameCol2 = new LinkButton();
                lnkProductNameCol2.Text = "Product Name";                   
                col2.Controls.Add(lnkProductNameCol2);

                LinkButton lnkProductNameCol3 = new LinkButton();
                lnkProductNameCol3.Text = "Product Name";                   
                col3.Controls.Add(lnkProductNameCol3);

                LinkButton lnkProductNameCol4 = new LinkButton();
                lnkProductNameCol4.Text = "Product Name";                  
                col4.Controls.Add(lnkProductNameCol4 );
            }
        }
```

Hope this help.